# AssociatedObject.DataContext is null in Behavior in ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to use a Behavior to trigger a method in the View from the VM. To this end, I use an object of type Trigger with an Event and invoker in the VM, and bind this to a dependency property in the behavior. The behavior does the subscription to the event in its Loaded callback. This works as expected, when the event in the VM is invoked, I can call the method in the view using AssociatedObject.

However, when the Behavior is inside a DataTemplate for a ContentPresenter, I see the following weird behavior (no pun intended...). Given a ContentPresenter with two DataTemplates, used depending on the type of Content (Tab1 or Tab2), when the Content is changed from Tab1 to Tab2, everything is fine. When it is changed from one instance of Tab1 to another instance of Tab1, however, AssociatedObject.DataContext is suddently null (and the method I try to call on the View fails due to this).

I tried to create a minimal example to demonstrate this. The code below should have everything to just run in a new WPF app. Observe the debug output in the following click paths to reproduce:

Tab -> Tab1 -> Invoke -> Output as expected

Tab -> Tab1a -> Tab1 -> Invoke -> DataContext is empty

Tab -> Tab1 -> Again as expected

I can think of ways to work around this problem, but I would like to understand it. I assume it is related to the DataTemplate not being rebuilt when the Content changes to the same type, but still I would expect AssociatedObject to point to the correct Grid (which I think it does not, since the DataContext in the actually shown Grid is fine). Any ideas are highly appreciated!

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="EmptyWpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EmptyWpfApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Tab}">
       <ContentPresenter.Resources>
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Tab1}">
               <Grid>
                   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                       <local:TestBehavior Trigger="{Binding T}"/>
                   </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                   <TextBlock>With behavior</TextBlock>
               </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Tab2}">
               <Grid>
                   <TextBlock>Empty</TextBlock>
               </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ContentPresenter.Resources>
   </ContentPresenter>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Tab</Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick1">Tab1</Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick1a">Tab1a</Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick2">Invoke on VM</Button>
</Grid>
```

MainWindows.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using EmptyWpfApp.Annotations;

namespace EmptyWpfApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window

{
    private Tab2 _tab = new Tab2();
    private Tab1 _tab1 = new Tab1();
    private Tab1 _tab1a = new Tab1();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ViewModel)DataContext).Tab = _tab;
    }
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ViewModel)DataContext).Tab = _tab1;
    }
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick1a(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ViewModel)DataContext).Tab = _tab1a;
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (((ViewModel) DataContext).Tab as Tab1)?.T.OnE();
    }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ITab _tab;

    public ITab Tab
    {
        get => _tab;
        set
        {
            _tab = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public interface ITab {}

public class Tab1 : ITab
{
    public Trigger T { get; } = new Trigger();
}

public class Tab2 : ITab {}

public class Trigger
{
    public event EventHandler E;

    public virtual void OnE()
    {
        E?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class TestBehavior : Behavior<Grid>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TriggerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Trigger",
        typeof(Trigger),
        typeof(TestBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(Trigger)));

    public Trigger Trigger {
        get => (Trigger)GetValue(TriggerProperty);
        set => SetValue(TriggerProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        AssociatedObject.Unloaded += Cleanup;
    }

    private void Cleanup(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Cleanup();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        Cleanup();
    }

    private void Cleanup()
    {
        AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        if (Trigger != null)
            Trigger.E -= TriggerOnE;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Subscribe();
    }

    private void Subscribe()
    {
        Trigger.E += TriggerOnE;
    }

        private void TriggerOnE(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("DC:" + AssociatedObject.DataContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this design is vastly more complicated than it needs to be. My guess is that you want the user to be able to choose among three different viewmodels for the window's main content, and then you have another button that invokes a method on the selected viewmodel. Is that correct? I think the solution is to start over with a conventional MVVM design, which is easier to get right the first time, and much easier to debug.

Comment: ...I might also add that if you used a ContentPresenter outside of a ControlTemplate, you don't understand ContentPresenter well enough to use it outside of a ControlTemplate. Outside of a ControlTemplate, always use ContentControl instead. ContentPresenter adds nothing that you want. But that doesn't appear to be the problem in this particular case.

Comment: It is a bit more complicated than that. The button is bound to a command in the VM, which will do some things there, and then should trigger a method in the view. We take the trip via the VM to collect some information, but then need to call a method on the control (it is a DevExpress grid control, and we want to export that grid).

Comment: .. and reg. ContentPresenter vs  ContentControl, thanks for the hint! Changing it does not change the behavior here, I tried that already in one of my increasingly desparate attempts...

Comment: Nothing in the VM should ever trigger anything in the view. The VM can define an event that it raises when such-and-such happens in a VM command. The view can handle that event and do something. Alternatively, you can use a click handler in the view that invokes a command on the VM and does other stuff also.  Keep it simple.

Comment: And how would you handle that event in the view? Basically, this is what we are trying to do, but avoiding to do stuff like `((ViewModel)DataContext).Event += ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194837/discussion-between-masiman-and-ed-plunkett).